# ElasticSearch : Concurrent updates to index while _reindex for the same index in progress

Tags: elasticsearch

We have been using this [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/index-aliases.html) as a reference to accommodate any change in the mappings for a field in our index with zero downtime.

Question:
Considering the same example taken in the above link,  when we reindex the data from
my_index_v1 to  my_index_v2 using [_reindex](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html) API. Does ElasticSearch guarantee that any concurrent updates happening in my_index_v1 would make it to my_index_v2 for sure?

For example, a document might get updated in my_index_v1 before or after it is reindexed by api to my_index_v2.

Ultimately, we just need to ensure that while we did not want any downtime for doing any mapping changes (hence did _reindex using alias and other cool stuff by ES), we also want to ensure that none of the add/update were missed while this huge reindex was in progress, as we are talking about reindexing >50GB data.

Thanks,
Sandeep

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reindex api will not consider the changes made after the process has started..
One thing you can do is once you are done reindexing process.You can again start process with **version_type:external**.
This will cause only documents from source index to destination index that have different version and are not present

Here is the example

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "twitter"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "new_twitter",
    "version_type": "external"
  }
}
```

Setting version_type to external will cause Elasticsearch to preserve the version from the source, create any documents that are missing, and update any documents that have an older version in the destination index than they do in the source index:

Comment: thank you for the solution. I'm trying to do as you mentioned but I'm getting version conflict errors when reindexing docs again with `"version_type": "external"`. This is the error: `version conflict, current version [1] is higher or equal to the one provided [1]` - can you suggest what am I doing wrong? my `_reindex` request payload is exactly as in your example but without version_type for the first reindex run and with version_type for the second run. I also used slices: auto and refresh: false but remove those query attrs does not change anything.

Answer (score 4):

One way to solve this is by using two aliases instead of one. One for queries (let’s call it *read_alias*), and one for indexing (*write_alias*). We can write our code so that all indexing happens through the *write_alias* and all queries go through the *read_alias*. Let's consider three periods of time:

**Before rebuild**

*read_alias*: points to *current_index*

*write_alias*: points to *current_index*
[image]

All queries return current data.

All modifications go into *current_index*.

**During rebuild**

*read_alias*: points to *current_index*

*write_alias*: points to *new_index*
[image]

All queries keep getting data as it existed before the rebuild, since searching code uses *read_alias*.

All rows, including modified ones, get indexed into the *new_index*, since both the rebuilding loop and the DB trigger use the *write_alias*.

**After rebuild**

*read_alias*: points to *new_index*

*write_alias*: points to *new_index*
[image]

All queries return new data, including the modifications made during rebuild.

All modifications go into *new_index*.

It should even be possible to get the modified data from queries while rebuilding, if we make the DB trigger code index modified rows into both the indices while the rebuild is going on (i.e., while the aliases point to different indices).

[image]

It is often better to rebuild the index from source data using custom code instead of relying on the *_reindex* API, since that way we can add new fields that may not have been stored in the old index.

[This article](https://medium.com/craftsmenltd/rebuild-elasticsearch-index-without-downtime-168363829ea4) has some more details.

Answer (score 1):

It *looks* like it does it based off of snapshots of the source index.

Which would suggest to me that they couldn't reasonably honor changes to the source happening in the middle of the process. You avoid downtime on the search side, but I think you would need to pause updates on the indexing side during this process.

Something you *could* do is keep track on your index of when the document was last modified. Then once you finish indexing and switch the alias, you query the old index for what changed in the middle. Propagate those changes over to the new index and you get eventual consistency.

Comment: Technically you'd also want to make sure the document you're replacing was not updated _again_ while you were trying to bring over changes. Messy stuff.